# What exactly started the war and who invaded them?

Tags: plot-explanation, tomorrow-when-the-war-began

In **Tomorrow When The War Began** (2010), there are a group of teenagers that decided to go camping in the outback.

They were there (I believe) for a little while, then one of them (I'm fairly sure it was one of the girls) woke up to a cloudy day and also with a large formation of war planes overhead heading in the direction of war.

[image]

In later scenes we see one of the teenagers house that has been raided and the dog dead. Also the fact that there was a big prison camp holding the teenagers parents. There was one man who went crazy, tried to hand fight one of the enemy soldiers and as a result, he was shot in the face.

[image]

The teenagers were then spotted and pursued but did not succeed with killing the teenagers.

There was a later scene of tanks crossing a bridge.

**What exactly started the war in the first place?**

Comment: As I remember, it was never explained. I don't think they even named the country that invaded them.

Comment: That is a plot hole then eh?

Comment: I was very curious about it because that was never mentioned during the movie.

Comment: I just modified the title, that will attract more people so then at least I could get an answer faster...if there is one.

Comment: It's deliberately not specified in the books, but I haven't seen the film.

Comment: If no one can even find an answer, this would be one very big plot hole.

Comment: No, it's not a plot hole, it's just simply never mentioned because it isn't relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## It is never revealed who the invading army are; but they appear to be invading due to the need for land.

It turns out that the *origin* of the invading army is *never revealed*. It is suggested that the original author did this in order to limit offending the country *in real life*, due to the way in which the army acts in the actual series. In my research, the enemies are shown to be (mostly) cruel and 'with no redeeming qualities'. I have found speculation that the army is *French*, *Chinese*, *Malaysian*, *Korean*, *Indonesian*, and more generically, *Asian*.

A constant motive I find is that the invading army wishes to take advantage of all of our undeveloped space. I guess no-body told them that it is undeveloped because it is *also*, mostly, *uninhabitable*.

---

#### We have more information on who they are *not*.

An article on *[rsimpson.id.au](http://www.rsimpson.id.au)* provides insight into what we know of the enemy, from the books:

> **[The Enemy at rsimpson.id.au](http://www.rsimpson.id.au/books/tomorrow/explore/enemy.html)**<sub>*(emphasis mine)*</sub>:
>   
>   Anyway, it is easier to identify who they are not. **They are not**:
>
> - **New Zealand** (as they fight on our side)
> - **Papua New Guinea** (as the fight on our side)
> - **The United States of America** (as they supply us with equipment)
> - **Japan** (as they supply us with equipment)
> - **India** (as they try and broker a peace deal)
>
> So who are they ? What are their characteristics ?
>
> - They speak a guttural language, with a sort of wailing music to it (*The Dead of the Night*, p44)
> - Their language is nothing that Fi recognises (and she knows about 6), **Lee doesn't recognise it and he knows Thai and Vietnamese, Homer does not recognise it and he knows Greek nor does Ellie (with her poor French)**.
> - **They are ruled by a general** - likely a military dictatorship (*Tomorrow, When the War Began*, p168)
> - **They have a large population, several times ours** (otherwise they wouldn't have a hope of pulling of an occupation)
> - **They use a different alphabet** to us *[Australians]*(*The Night is for Hunting*, p128 - a soap packet wrapper)
> - **They were either colonised by a European power with a royal family or have one of their own** (*The Other Side of Dawn*, p192 - Colonel Long's rank insignia is three crowns) but not by the British as the invader's insignia for a Colonel is a crown and two stars.
> - They have at least one aircraft carrier (*The Third Day*, The Frost, p82)
> - **They have a base nearby to Victoria** (that's where they invade, and for a successful invasion you need a nearby base, see [Invading Australia](http://www.rsimpson.id.au/books/tomorrow/explore/invasion.html#4)

The author of the article goes on to suggest that *what we know* does not match *any* single country, and that they believe this to have been a deliberate plot device, on part of John Marsden. The author makes note of a popular theory that the army is simply *Asian*, but comments that *they* interpret the army as *French*.

---

#### There is suggestion that the invaders are a *South Asian* coalition.

The Wikipedia article on the series comments that the invading army is a coalition of *South Asian* countries, seeking a solution to over-population.

> **["Tomorrow series" at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrow_series)** <sub>*(emphasis mine)*</sub>
>   
>   Likewise, no parts of the war outside Ellie's immediate perspective are covered; the reader is not informed exactly how much of the country is under enemy control, or how well the war is going for the Australian military. However **the invaders are described in the series as a coalition of highly populous South Asian nations seeing the vast underdeveloped spaces of Australia as a way to tackle their overpopulation (Most likely Indonesia, Malaysia and the Philippines)** and the series features multinational colonies of enemy civilians being set up in conquered territory.

---

#### Another user finds a lot of similarities with *Indonesia*.

A user has also asked about the army, on *[Quora](https://www.quora.com/)*, and once again, we are only met with speculation:

> **["In John Marsden's Tomorrow, when the war began, who is the invading army" at Quora](https://www.quora.com/In-John-Marsdens-Tomorrow-when-the-war-began-who-is-the-invading-army)**<sub>*(emphasis mine)*</sub>
>   
>   <sub>Beren Wollensack, Lives in Australia, misses Harambe</sub>
>   <sup>Updated Feb 10 2016</sup>
>
> "**It is never actually mentioned, in the books or movies. It is likely to be Indoneisa, our neighbour to the North has a strong military, and they have a lot of peopl<sup>*[sic]*</sup> and not enough space. They aren't as fortunate as Australia for sure, and in the movie, it is mentioned that the invaders are Australia's "less fortunate neighbours**<sup>*[sic]*</sup>."
>
> **It can't be China**, simply because then New Zealand, even in with their military super boosted by the war, would never be able to win against China. **Apparently the North Korean flag can be seen on the helmets of the soldiers in the movie**, and it makes sense, nobody from North Korea will ever be offended by this, and I didn't notice this flag at all, keeping in mind I learnt<sup>*[sic]*</sup> this fact after watching the movie. The invading army seems far two equipped and capable, with tw<sup>*[sic]*</sup> is, army, and good aircraft, to be the DPRK. And even then, the U.S. Would probably jump at the chance to save a nation from invasion from North Korea, especially a western country, and an ally.
>
> **I can't see it being China or North Korea, so even though technically, the answer is nothing, because it is never mentioned, but I would have to say Indonesia**, Papua New Guinea was allied with Australia during this war, and they also wouldn't be able to successfully take over Australia. The same with Malaysia, but they don't have a very high population, so they wouldn't need to invade as much as indoneisa<sup>*[sic]*</sup> would. I guess it could be Singapore, they have a strong airforce, but because they probably don't have a good enough population for the invasion, and they could easily be beaten by Indonesia, even though I think Singapore has a better airforce, if they were to invade Australia, assuming indoneisa<sup>*[sic]*</sup> doesn't help."

Comment: OK, good answer, but no need for the severe downvotes.